# ActiveListioner Executing after Build Flutter Error

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check firebase database using flutter to see if user who is logged in is registered or not so checking to see if firstname exist in user database but what is happening is that the activeListeners function is always executing after rmn() function which should not happen. activeListeners should execute before rmn() .

Here is my code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:after_layout/after_layout.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:ayto_driver_x/signup.dart';
import 'package:ayto_driver_x/mainpage.dart';
import 'package:ayto_driver_x/login.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'After Layout - Good Example',
  home: new LoginState(),
);
 }
 }

class LoginState extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 HomeScreenState createState() => new HomeScreenState();
  }

 class HomeScreenState extends State<LoginState> with AfterLayoutMixin<LoginState> {

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

   String srm="";
   final _database=FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

   @override
   void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
activeListeners();
}
void activeListeners(){
final User? user=auth.currentUser;
final id=user?.uid ;
_database.child('Driver/${user?.uid}/FirstName').onValue.listen((event) {
  final Object? description=event.snapshot.value ?? false;
  setState(() {
    print('DescriptionLS=$description');
    srm='$description';
    print('SRMx1=$srm');

  });
});
   }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
activeListeners();
return new Scaffold(body: new Container(color: Colors.white));
}

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
// Calling the same function "after layout" to resolve the issue.
activeListeners();
rmn();
   }

 void rmn()
 {

FirebaseAuth.instance
    .authStateChanges()
    .listen((User? user) {
  if (user == null) {
    print('User is currently signed out!');
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,

      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),

      ),
          (e) => false,
    );
  }
  else {
    activeListeners();

    print('User is signed in!');
    print('SRMxc=$srm');
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: srm,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    );
    if(srm.compareTo('false')==0) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const SignupScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
    else {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,

        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const MainPage(),

        ),
            (e) => false,
      );


    }
  }
});

  }
   }
```

Log File :

```
I/flutter ( 5748): User is signed in!
I/flutter ( 5748): SRMxc=
I/flutter ( 5748): DescriptionLS=false
I/flutter ( 5748): SRMx1=false
I/flutter ( 5748): DescriptionLS=false
I/flutter ( 5748): SRMx1=false
I/flutter ( 5748): DescriptionLS=false
I/flutter ( 5748): SRMx1=false
I/flutter ( 5748): DescriptionLS=false
I/flutter ( 5748): SRMx1=false
```

Please suggest me a solution to execute activeListeners() before rmn().

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AmrYousef , I am Asking how to execute ActiveListioners() function before rmn() , Thats it. Thank You.

Comment: Please Don't Start All Words With Capital Letters. It Is Very Annoying To Read Text Like This.

Comment: Thanks @JamesZ For Properly Editing the question . Will Follow Your Suggestions From Next Question Onwards.